# Have the results come back yet?

Tags: grammar, american-english, british-english

I would just like to ask which of the sentences are correct and which are not?

1. Have the test results come back yet? (This is what I usually use. But I heard someone say come up but not sure if what he said was correct)
2. Have the test results come up yet?
3. Have the test results come out yet?
4. Have the test results turned up yet?

Thanks

Comment: In the US results "come back" from the laboratory or whatever where the analysis is performed.  One could use other expressions, but "come back" is idiomatic, and its literal meaning fits the circumstances pretty well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are all correct but they have slightly different meanings.

If the results have "come back", it suggests that you or someone else sent them off somewhere or to someone (or perhaps they were sent automatically) and that they have since been returned by that person or agency.  For example, "have the results come back from the lab?"

If the results have "come up", this suggests that they have appeared on a display.  "Have the results come up on the computer yet?"

If the results have "come out", this means they've been released or distributed.  It suggests publication, though there are other interpretations.  "The results will be in the newspaper once they've come out."
See https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/come_out

If the results have "turned up", it suggests they may have previously been mislaid or lost.  "Those results we were looking for - have they turned up yet?"
See https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/turn_up